# How do I make it so when I input chairsale < 0 it doesn't loop back to desktable input if I just want it to loop on chair input till it isn't below 0

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

```
saleperson = int(input("Please input salesperson ID or -1 to end: "))
while saleperson != -1:
    desksale = int(input("Enter desk sales: "))
    if desksale < 0:
        print("Invalid desk sales please enter a positive number")
    else:
        tablesale = int(input("Enter table sales: "))
        if tablesale < 0:
            print("Invalid table sales please enter a positive number")
        else:
            chairsale = int(input("Enter chair sales: "))
            if chairsale < 0:
                print("Invalid chair sale please enter a positive number")
            else:
                saleperson = int(input("Please input salesperson ID or -1 to end: "))
```

Whenever I type in -1 for tablesale it goes back to ask for desksale I want it to just repeat ask for tablesale till I put in a positive number.

My code is suppose to be based on this rubric

> create a program that prompts the user to type in a Salesperson’s
> o ID
> o table sales
> o desks sales
> o chair sales
> if the user enters invalid data (such as negative chair sales) then a message should
> appear stating “Invalid: Enter valid chair sales:”
> o the program should not continue until the user enters valid data
> the program then calculates the commission on the sales based on the above table
> the program should then prompt the user whether to process another Salesperson
> o the process should be repeated until the user decides not to continue
> once the user has decided not to enter another salesperson data, two tables should
> appear, a sales table and a commission table
> the sales table displays on each row
> o each sales person’s ID, table sales, desk sales and chair sales
> o the last row displays total table sales, total desk sales, and total chair sales
> the commission table displays on each row
> o each salesperson’s ID, table commission, desk commission and chair
> commission
> o the last row displays total table commission, total desk commission and total
> chair commission

Answer (score 0):

You need to have multiple while loops checking the conditions as you need to check whether every single input is a valid number and check them until the user enters a valid input. I have adjusted the code according to the rubric that you posted.

```
saleperson = int(input("Please input salesperson ID or -1 to end: "))
while saleperson != -1:
    desksale = int(input("Enter desk sales: "))
    while desksale < 0:
        desksale = int(input("Invalid desk sales please enter a positive number:"))

    tablesale = int(input("Enter table sales: "))
    while tablesale < 0:
        tablesale = int(input("Invalid table sales please enter a positive number:"))
    chairsale = int(input("Enter chair sales: "))
    while chairsale < 0:
        chairsale = int(input("Invalid chair sale please enter a positive number:"))
    saleperson = int(input("Please input salesperson ID or -1 to end: "))
```

Here I am making sure that all the inputs for sale are not negative numbers and when the user enters `-1` to the `saleperson` the program will stop immediately.

This only works if the user only enters integers. you should try to validate that the inputs are numbers and won't run into an error when the user enters a string.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is going back to ask for *desksale* when you type -1 is because the statement `if tablesale < 0`  will evaluate to **True**, causing your program to execute `print("Invalid table sales please enter a positive number")` and then return to the beginning of the while loop, since *saleperson* is still < 0.

Instead of using the *saleperson* variable as the condition for the while loop, try using a Boolean flag instead that you can switch to True or False depending on the other variable assignments, or just use a `while True`. Even though it’s a discouraged approach, it gets the job done as long as you are careful where you place your `break` statements to prevent infinite loops.

I would also not recommend you locking the user in a question until you obtain the expected answer. It is a better approach throwing an explanatory error to the user, and then start all the prompts from the beginning. Something like this:

```py
while True:

    saleperson = int(input("Please input salesperson ID or -1 to end: "))
    if saleperson == -1:
        break # Here’s your exit
   
    desksale = int(input("Enter desk sales: "))
    if desksale < 0:
        print("Invalid desk sales! Please enter a positive number or 0")
        continue # Restart the loop
    
    tablesale = int(input("Enter table sales: "))
    if tablesale < 0:
        print("Invalid table sales! Please enter a positive number or 0")
        continue # Restart the loop
       
    chairsale = int(input("Enter chair sales: "))
    if chairsale < 0:
        print("Invalid chair sales! Please enter a positive number or 0”)
        # No need to restart the loop as it will automatically restart because there is no more code to execute
```